# joomla site having dual behaviour

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla1.5

i have a site http://www.carsharehfx.ca/index.php,It is opening in Chrome only but not opening in IE or firefox.It was woking properly butit happens todays morning.please anyone who can guide me on this.I dont know which tool to use to inspect this,even firebug will not help me

Comment: It opens in IE 8 and Firefox, it just takes too long to load the page. According to firebug it took almost 22 seconds to 'receive' the homepage. Take a look at the slider on the bottom.

Comment: Have you changed Joomla at all since the time it was working? If yes, it might be a good idea to uninstall each component one at a time until you find what is breaking your site.

Comment: I see you solved the problem. Would be great if you wrote what was the problem in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually firebug helps a bit because you can see you get internal server error 500. So the problem may be not in joomla itself but in your server configuration.

Comment: Indeed, firebug should at the very least give you an indication about what is taking so long to load.